Missing signing identifier when creating an archive for an ios app containing a static library built with cmake
I'm developing an application with Flutter that is available for iOS and Android. Part of this application requires signal processing and has been developed in C++ and compiled into a static library via cmake for use on both OSes. The compilation went well and the application was created correctly. In debug mode, I can launch the application in the iOS simulator and on my phone without any problems. However, when I try to create an archive with XCode (version 15.4 (15F31d)) I get this error message ‘Missing signing identifier’ about an executable produced by cmake. I've tried signing the library with the codesign utility but that doesn't solve the problem.

I tried to set those variables with the correct values but the problem persists

XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY
XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVELOPMENT_TEAM

Since my library is static and embedded in the application code, I should only have to sign the application and this step is managed automatically by Xcode

looks like Xcode is trying to sign cmake build artifacts. they should not be part of your library's package

I use the structure I always use for my cmake project, so you are saying that xcode is trying to sign everything in the build folder and I should tell it to only sign the library and to ignore any other cmake artefacts?

I solved my problem. I added the sources of my library as a reference in xcode but the sources wasn't part of any xcode build. It wasto have to have the ability to modify them directly in xcode while working on the ios specific side. But apparently, xcodedidn't like that and when I removed the sources from xcode I was able to create the ipa
